# Radare2 C output

Tags: c, radare2

I made a simple hello world program, and put it in radare2. I then ran the `pc` command, which displayed C output. The output was this:

```
#define _BUFFER_SIZE 256
const uint8_t buffer[256] = {
  0x55, 0x48, 0x89, 0xe5, 0x48, 0x83, 0xec, 0x10, 0x48, 0x8d,
  0x3d, 0x3b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc7, 0x45, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x00, 0xe8, 0x0d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x31,
  0xc9, 0x89, 0x45, 0xf8, 0x89, 0xc8, 0x48, 0x83, 0xc4, 0x10,
  0x5d, 0xc3, 0xff, 0x25, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x8d,
  0x1d, 0x71, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x53, 0xff, 0x25, 0x61,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90, 0x68, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe9,
  0xe6, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20,
  0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x34, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x8b, 0x0f,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00,
  0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x0f, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

The issue is that I do not know how to properly use this output (compile it, use it, etc). If anybody can help please do. Thanks!

Comment: It will only print the current location as a c-style array. You can use this if you want to use the buffer in your code...

Comment: @mrexodia please consider reformulating the content of your comment as an answer for the sake of other people with similar questions.

Comment: @mrexodia yeah I know, but I don't know how to use the buffer...

Comment: Neither do I, why do you want a C buffer?

Comment: @mrexodia I was wondering how to use it...

Comment: An example use case might be: you found encrypted malware config at a certain location, you dump it to a C buffer and maybe write some decryptor in C for that buffer. Radare prints what you ask it to so you are the one deciding what to use it for basically...

Comment: @mrexodia please consider reformulating the content of your comments as an answer for the sake of other people with similar questions

Answer (score 20):

The `pc` command will output *n* bytes from the current seek (`s`) as a C array, where *n* is the Block size (`b`) or the length mentioned in the command.

The output is then can be used to, for example, manipulate the array outside of radare2, build a shellcode, decrypt a buffer and so on.

Let's demonstrate it with a simple example.
Here's a tiny HelloWorld.c program:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

Let's compile it with `gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld` and open it with radare2 `r2 -A HelloWorld`

Now let's seek to `main` and print the function:

```
[0x00400400]> s main
[0x004004d7]> pdf
            ;-- main:
/ (fcn) sym.main 17
|  sym.main ();
|           ; DATA XREF from 0x0040041d (entry0)
|       0x004004d7      55             push rbp
|       0x004004d8      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
|       0x004004db      bf74054000     mov edi, str.Hello__World_ ; "Hello, World!"
|       0x004004e0      e80bffffff     call sym.imp.puts          ; int puts(const char *s)
|       0x004004e5      90             nop
|       0x004004e6      5d             pop rbp
\       0x004004e7      c3             ret
```

As I said, just a simple Hello World program :)

Now, instead of printing the disassembly let's print only the hex bytes of the function using `pxf`:

```
0x004004d7  5548 89e5 bf74 0540 00e8 0bff ffff 905d  UH...t.@.......]
0x004004e7  c3
```

These are the hex-bytes which represent the function.
To the final part, using `bf sym.main` let's define the current Block size to be as the size of `main`, and then print the C-array using `pc`:

```
[0x004004d7]> bf sym.main
[0x004004d7]> pc
#define _BUFFER_SIZE 17
const uint8_t buffer[17] = {
  0x55, 0x48, 0x89, 0xe5, 0xbf, 0x74, 0x05, 0x40, 0x00, 0xe8,
  0x0b, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x90, 0x5d, 0xc3
};
```

You can easily see that the array is structured from the hex bytes we printed before, from 0x55 (`push rbp`) to 0xc3 (`return`).  That's it.

Let's say for example that you  disassembled a program and spotted a XOR encrypted data and you want to dump it to a C program and manipulate it there. In such case you need to seek to the offset of the encrypted data (`s <addr>`), define the block size to be the length of the data (`b 150`) and then dump it as a C-array using `pc` (or as a python array using `pcp`).

---

**Decompilation**
Some people expect the `pc` command to be a decompilation of the program to C. If you want to decompile a function to C in radare you can use one of the following ways:

The `pdc` command to print C-like syntax:

```
function sym.main () {
    loc_0x4004d7:

     //DATA XREF from 0x0040041d (entry0)
       push rbp                 
       rbp = rsp                
       edi = str.Hello__World ; "Hello, World!"                                                                       
       int puts(const char * s : 0x00400574 = Hello, World!)                                    
       pop rbp                  

}
```

Use [`r2dec`](https://github.com/wargio/r2dec-js) - a plugin to radare that can produce a pseudo-C output
Use [`radeco`](https://github.com/radareorg/radeco) - a radare decompiler tool based on radeco-lib.
Use [`r2snowman`](https://github.com/radare/radare2-extras/tree/master/r2snowman) - radare2 plugin which integrates the snowman decompiler.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to expand on MegaBeets awesome answer. I don't see the point of `pdc`. It seems more wrong and less high-level.

`pdf` is awesome for my use cases. If I want something high level, I'll use [`pdd` with r2dec](https://github.com/wargio/r2dec-js). You can install it with `r2pm -i r2dec`.

```
[0x0000063a]> pdd
/* r2dec pseudo C output */
#include <stdint.h>

void main (void) {
    puts ("Hello, World!");
}
```

For more information see

- [How does r2dec compare to `pdc`?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17910/22669)