# How does r2dec compare to pdc?

Tags: disassembly, radare2

Radare has a command `pdc`

```
pdc   pseudo disassembler output in C-like syntax
```

I'm curious to know how the plugin [`r2dec-js`](https://github.com/wargio/r2dec-js) compares to `pdc` it seems like they do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a huge difference between `pdc` and `pdd` (r2dec).

- `pdc` provide a basic r2 pseudo code with some and it's mostly for x86/x64.
- `pdd` provides a more advance pseudo-C like code where the controlflow, instructions, delayed branches, etc.. have been analyzed and tries to provide some slightly more readable code to the user.

`pdd` is only available after installing r2dec from `r2pm`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for a high level run down of the differences. Thanks.